# Issuing comparing image from database in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have image View , button and text in my activity , I want the following things:  firstly when i click on button it will open the gallery and when i select image from gallery it shown in my image view , secondly when the image is shown it will compare from my database images which are already saved there if image match then show image found and show the user data like age contact and name in my textview or if image not same then show image not found . for the comparison. How can i Solve it????

I know that we need a comparison algorithm but here i am just doing a simple method by comparing tha upload Uri and the Database image Url but after uploading the image in my app it showing image not found i try every method by checking Catlog also debug mode but not finding the problem.

Here is my Activity:

```
package com.example.abnormal_person_app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

public class Fetch_image extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button uploadImageButton;
    private TextView userInfoTextView;
    private Uri selectedImageUri;

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_REFERENCE = "users"; // Adjust this to your Firebase Realtime Database reference


    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Disable the back button by not calling super.onBackPressed()
        // You can add any custom logic here if needed
        // For example, show a message to the user or do nothing
        // To re-enable the back button, simply remove this method override

        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fetch_image);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);


        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        uploadImageButton = findViewById(R.id.uploadImageButton);
        userInfoTextView = findViewById(R.id.userInfoTextView);

        uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

            Log.d("SelectedImageURI", selectedImageUri.toString());

            // You have the selected image URI, now proceed with image comparison
            compareImageWithDatabase();
        }
    }

    private void compareImageWithDatabase() {
        // Convert the selected image URI to a string (e.g., Firebase Storage reference or download URL)
        String selectedImagePath = selectedImageUri.toString();

        Log.d("SelectedImagePath", selectedImagePath);

        // Initialize Firebase Database reference
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(DATABASE_REFERENCE);

        // Query the Firebase Realtime Database to find a user with a matching image path
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("imageUrl").equalTo(selectedImagePath);

        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = task.getResult();
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    // Match found - retrieve user data
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        if (user != null) {
                            displayUserData(user.getName(), user.getAge(), user.getContact());
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // No match found
            Log.d("ImageComparison", "No match found");
            displayNotFound();
        });
    }

    private void displayUserData(String name, int age, String contact) {
        String userData = "Name: " + name + "\nAge: " + age + "\nContact: " + contact;
        userInfoTextView.setText(userData);

        Log.d("DisplayUserData", "User data displayed: " + userData);
    }

    private void displayNotFound() {
        userInfoTextView.setText("Image not found");

        Log.d("DisplayNotFound", "Image not found");
    }
}
```

Here is my database structure:

```
users
-NgKo_poWoq4PygtChdk
age
:
12

contact
:
"03120767949"
imageUrl
:
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/abnormal-person-app.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2Fnull_1696878188592.jpg?alt=media&token=6fbed5a0-dba8-46e5-8801-b68ead8f1edf"
name
:
"iftikhat"
-NgQowbH84HGMWLxXmTd
age
:
25
contact
:
"213487878"
imageUrl
:
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/abnormal-person-app.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2Fnull_1696978942978.jpg?alt=media&token=4a515511-0d64-4d9e-a80a-6d5b5a98034e"
name
:
"kahan"
-NgR1PG5xirNZruKiXW9
age
:
25
contact
:
"87876784"
imageUrl
:
Value
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/abnormal-person-app.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2Fnull_1696982473830.jpg?alt=media&token=c54b0531-34a8-4241-bdb1-d62542cb026e
name
:
"apcho"
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back_klia"
    tools:context=".Fetch_image">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder_image"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/uploadImageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Upload Image"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userInfoTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:hint="User's Info will Appear here if Match Found....."
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/whatsapp_imgview"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/whatapp_pic"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe the image you get, convert it to byte and compare the byte you shared in database.

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

How you are uploading your image to storage?
In your database you are storing the path of firebase storage where your image stored on server and your local path/uri is different, You should add new field in your database like `localPath` that will store local path/uri then you can fetch data with `localPath`

Comment: I created a local path in my database, but when I upload an image the Selected image path and Image Uri are the same but when I see the database the image path is totally different. How I can do the same address for the database path image and the uploading image?  I tried another way by normalizing the path but it didn't work for me, is there any other option?

Comment: You need to have two different field in your database, one field `localPath` will contain local uri/path and another one field `imageUrl` will contain your server image path, then you need to check database using localPath like ```databaseReference.orderByChild("localPath").equalTo(selectedImagePath)```